# Shuffle instruction in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, shuffle

I am new to cuda so maybe this will be noob question, but here we go...

I can't use shuffle instructions in my kernel and I don't know why. I have Quadro K620 with compute capability 5.0, but instruction such as `__shfl_down` aren't recognized. I am using Visual Studio 2013. I can go to definition of these instructions, but condition `defined(__CUDACC__)` in `sm_30_intrinsics.h` makes every definition unreachable. Is problem in project settings or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use nvcc compiler flags `sm_30` and `compute_30` or higher in order to be able to use `__shfl` instructions.